# Use PHP to split string by tags and replace each tag with unique values

Tags: php, html, split, preg-match

I have a string that has field place holders in it.  I need to split the string by those placeholders and return the string and placeholders into a single array.

For example, if I had the string:

```
Ohio is one of the original [s] in the northwest territory.  [s] and [s] were also part of the northwest territory.  Which states are missing [a]?
```

I would like to see it split into an array:

```
[0] => Ohio is one of the original
[1] => [s]
[2] => in the northwest territory.
[3] => [s]
[4] => and
[5] => [s]
[6] => were also part of the northwest territory.  Which states are missing 
[7] => [a]
[8] => ?
```

To satisfy those who assume we never read manuals, here are a couple pieces of code I've tried ... I just can't get the array in the format listed above.  The closest I've come is this but it still gets more text than I need in some parts of the array.  I'll admit, I've never been a REGEX expert so your help is appreciated.

I'm matching on any one character enclosed in [] i.e. [a], [b], [e], etc.

```
preg_match_all("/(.*?)\[(.)\](.*?)/",$string,$x,PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($x);
```

Comment: Did you try anything yet? How about http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Comment: It's easy to throw RTFM at someone isn't it.  Yes, I've been playing with preg_match, preg_split, preg_match_all and a number of different permutations of all three but I figured I was just missing something easy.

Answer (score 1):

While I was originally offended by the obnoxious answer from rjdown, I did revisit all my examples and found an option that works.  Including the "-1" is what finally did the trick.  Thanks rjdown

```
$results =preg_split("/(\[.\])/i",$string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

The result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Ohio is one of the original 
    [1] => [s]
    [2] =>  in the northwest territory.  
    [3] => [s]
    [4] =>  and 
    [5] => [s]
    [6] =>  were also part of the northwest territory.  Which states are missing 
    [7] => [a]
    [8] => ?
)
```

Comment: Obnoxious? All you posted was what you wanted to do, with no evidence that you'd tried anything to solve it. That's not how stackoverflow works. Pointing you in the direction of a potentially useful function is more than most will do here. Normally all you'd get is a link to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask